# Not allowing to execute the Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to execute my sp using dynamic sql where iam passing the database name in a parameter

If I am using this way i have to use floowing code

```
use @dbName

go

exec(@Sql)
```

where @dbName is reffered for the datbase name and @Sql reffers an entire queries which i want to execute
Iam using Sql server 2005
and my code is as follows

```
set @cSQL=@dbName+'.dbo.sp_helptext '''+@cName+''''
```

now i want to execute this stored procedure so target database is new database, it needs an `use @dbname` in next line Go followed by an sql statement

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Can you specify what database you are using? What code you are using?

Comment: Why don't you just make the `use` command part of your dynamic sql?

Comment: You can't execute a use @variable name, not in MS SQL Server anyway

Comment: @David: ican make the use command but it needs an go command in next line it is not happening

Comment: You can use `USE [db]` in dynamic sql, but you have to "double-wrap" the following SQL commands in order for it to be effective.  I.E., `EXEC('USE db; Exec(''..sql commands..''); ';`.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this and it works on SQL Server 2000 without a `USE` or a `GO`...

```
declare @dbname as varchar(100), @sql as varchar(100)
set @dbname = 'my-database'
set @sql = 'my-stored-procedure'

set @Sql = QUOTENAME(@dbName) + '.dbo.sp_helptext ''' + @Sql + ''''
exec(@Sql)
```